# What is the name of the Qt widget used for filling text in gnome planner?

Tags: qt, treeview, gnome

The screen shot has been attached.

There is a kind of tree shaped widget in which you can fill in details, I wish to know its name.

Do `QTreeWidget` or `QTreeView` do the trick?

Do we have such a widget in Qt (in which text can be entered at run time[image])?

Comment: You mean "**a** QT widget **similar to the one** used in Gnome planner", right?

Comment: Yes @Complicatedseebio A tree style in which we can enter text, and clicking can create a sub tree etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `QTreWidget` is used when you want to display a simple tree with standard items.

> The QTreeWidget class is a convenience class that provides a standard
>   tree widget with a classic item-based interface similar to that used
>   by the QListView class in Qt 3. This class is based on Qt's Model/View
>   architecture and uses a default model to hold items, each of which is
>   a QTreeWidgetItem.

The `QTreeView` is used when you have more complex models and gives you more flexibility

> A QTreeView implements a tree representation of items from a model.
>   This class is used to provide standard hierarchical lists that were
>   previously provided by the QListView class, but using the more
>   flexible approach provided by Qt's model/view architecture.

I believe (I have not checked the corresponding code) that in the Gnome planner what you see is can be implemented `QTreeView` with custom `QAbstractItemDelegate`. Notice though but most Gnome applications use `GTK` and not `Qt`.

> The QAbstractItemDelegate class is used to display and edit data items
>   from a model.
>
> A QAbstractItemDelegate provides the interface and common
>   functionality for delegates in the model/view architecture. Delegates
>   display individual items in views, and handle the editing of model
>   data.

You should study the [Qt Model/View Programming](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html). It may has a steep learning curve but once you get familiar with it you can implement almost everything.

Answer (score 0):

On some other forum I have been told that there are editable trees in Qt:
http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtwidgets-itemviews-editabletreemodel-example.html

Here we can add/remove columns and text.